# how to stop /etc/profile.d/ from loading on startup

Tags: boot

I've bricked by RaspberryPi by installing a script into /etc/profile.d/

Apparently adding init=/bin/sh to cmdline.txt has not stopped the /etc/prpfile.d/ script from running. Is there a way to modify a config file from Windows to stop the /etc/profile.d/ script from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may get another SD card and USB SD card reader, then you may put a fresh image on your new card, put the old one in the USB reader, and modify the old one from the familiar linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Files in `/etc/profile.d` are sourced from the `/etc/profile` script; this is the final block in mine from raspbian:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
        for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
                if [ -r $i ]; then
                        . $i
                fi
        done
        unset i
fi
```

I doubt it is sourced from more than one place, so if you comment out that block (or just the `. $i` line in the middle), it won't be read.

The reason using `sh` instead of `bash` didn't change anything is that `sh` is also suppose to read `/etc/profile` at login ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files_for_shells)).

2) Probably simpler and more foolproof: just rename `/etc/profile.d`:

```
mv /etc/profile.d /etc/profile.d-MOVED
```

Although I guess if you could do this, you could just remove the offending file.  Note sure under what circumstances you will have read access to "modify a config file" but not (re)move one -- but good luck.